# Conditional properties in a C# project file

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj

I use a `Directory.Build.props` file that has a certain group of properties that I want to include only if the project has `GeneratePackageOnBuild` set to `true`, or when the project is packaged.

This is for the latest version of `.Net 7`.

The example below does not appear to be working.

Directory.Build.props

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(GeneratePackageOnBuild)' == 'true'">
    <PackageIcon>favicon.ico</PackageIcon>
    <PackageReadmeFile>README.md</PackageReadmeFile>
    <PublishRepositoryUrl>true</PublishRepositoryUrl>
    <EmbedUntrackedSources>true</EmbedUntrackedSources>
    <IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
    <SymbolPackageFormat>snupkg</SymbolPackageFormat>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Project.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: [Quote](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build): *Directory.Build.props is imported very early in Microsoft.Common.props, and properties defined later are unavailable to it. So, avoid referring to properties that are not yet defined (and will evaluate to empty).*  Rename the file to Directory.Build.targets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Directory.Build.props` file is imported before the content of the project file. The `GeneratePackageOnBuild` property hasn't yet been set to true when the `"'$(GeneratePackageOnBuild)' == 'true'"` condition is evaluated.

Move your `PropertyGroup` to the `Directory.Build.targets` file. The `Directory.Build.targets` file is imported after the content of the project file.

Contrary to what the names may seem to imply, there are no special restrictions. Both the `Directory.Build.props` file and the `Directory.Build.targets` file can contain properties, items, and targets.

In practice `Directory.Build.props` is hardly ever actually needed. Only when a property must be set before the project SDK (i.e. `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"`) logic is evaluated is there a need for the `Directory.Build.props` file. Everything else either can go or must go (because of dependencies) in the `Directory.Build.targets` file.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of the targets file.  I'll need to do some more reading on the subject, the link provided by @Hans Passant above will help I'm sure.